# How I can get the pk in the home view www.mywebsite.com

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I tried to get the pk from this function `def home_view(request, pk):` but because this in home view `www.site.com` it return error **home_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'** so it is didn't worked with me

#### My qustion is how I can pass pk to the template that in website domain without any extra urls like this

#### `www.site.com`

My view

```
def home_screen_view(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    post= Post.objects.filter(pk=pk) #here I want to get the pk
    comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post)

return render(request, 'personal/home.html', {'comment': comment)
```

My Urls

```
path('', home_screen_view, name='home'),
```

## Edit

Firstly I return my posts using list [], I need the pk of the post because the comment model is separate from the post model so I use the pk to use in this function

```
  posts = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
  comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post)



 post = []
  for u in users:
       p = Account.objects.get(username=u)
       posts = p.post_set.all()
       p_posts = p.video_set.all()
  post .append(p_posts)
  my_posts = request.user.post_set.all()
  post.append(my_posts)
  if len(post):
       post = sorted(chain(*post), reverse=True, key=lambda post: post.created_date)
```

My comment MPTT model

```
class PostCommentIDF(MPTTModel):

post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pos_com')
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='post_children')
author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Post Model

```
 class Post(models.Model):
 author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My template that related to render the comments

```
   {% recursetree video.total_comts %}
    <div id="{{ node.id }}" class="my-2 p-2" style="border: 0px solid grey"> 
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                      {{ node.publish|naturaltime }}           
            <div class="node-content mt-3">{{ node.content  }}</div>
                    </div>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Comment: you can pass it with the request body.

Comment: Are you showing any post on home screen?

Comment: show your `urls.py` please

Comment: @SergeyPugach Yes I showing posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution One

As you do not pass the `pk` information from url, you can't use `pk` in the view. So change the view to:

```
def home_screen_view(request):
   #rest of the code
```

Instead of `pk`, if you want to see the logged in user's posts, you can use:

```
def home_screen_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(account__user=request.user)  # assuming there is a FK relation in Account model.
```

### Solution Two

Also, you can't find pk arbitarily in the home view at `/` url, unless you pass it like `/12/`, if you pass that value then you need to update url code:

```
path('<int:pk>/', home_screen_view, name='home'),
```

### Solution Three

You can use url querystring to get the primary key:

```
def home_screen_view(request):
   pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
   posts = Posts.objects.all()
   if pk:
      posts = posts.filter(pk=pk)
```

Then use the browser url should look like `https://example.com/?pk=1`.

### Update

If you want to get post specific comments, then you can use following solution:

```
# view
def home_screen_view(request):
   return render(request, 'personal/home.html', {'posts': Post.objects.filter(author__user=request.user)})

# template
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}  // if you use related_name in PostCommentIDF then you need to use post.<related_name>.all
      {{ comment }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello I tried the Solution number 1 it is work but my posts is related to "mptt model commnets" so the all coments from the db returning to any post without specific post `posts = Post.objects.filter(author__username=request.user)
    comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post__in=posts)`

Comment: How about `PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post__author__user=request.user)`? But if you need post specific comments, then you can use a different approach.

Comment: Please see the update section of the answer

Comment: hello it is return nothing, I created this post because someone said to me creat a new qustionso, so there is no sufficient details because the details is in my previous qustion, do you like I edit my qustion and add the all details?

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Comment: i UPDATED MY qustion it is my fault because I didn't proved the details

Comment: Thank you sair for your help, I updated my qustion

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have not worked with mptt, so can't help you there. But I do not understand why you are using `recursetree` as posts and comments are different models(maybe my lack of knowledge in mptt)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help, I Using rescue because I followed a youtube video and It is worked with me when I worked with a specific post URL like `www.site.com/post1` and I tried to use it in home page but I should get the post pk and put it inside the comment model, again thank you

Comment: Maybe you can add a new answer to this question with what you have tried and worked. It might help someone with simillar issue in future. :)

Comment: Ok bro, I will do